# Get list of all user from Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

i try to get list of all users from Azure Devops with postman,

i tried  this link : [https://titi.net/{organization}/_apis/graph/users/{userDescriptor}?api-version=6.0-preview.1&userDescriptor=username&organization=titiproject](https://titi.net/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/graph/users/%7BuserDescriptor%7D?api-version=6.0-preview.1&userDescriptor=username&organization=titiproject)

[image]

Comment: Can you please try to use this given API `GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users?subjectTypes={subjectTypes}&continuationToken={continuationToken}&scopeDescriptor={scopeDescriptor}&api-version=6.0-preview.1` . Reference [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT how can i take {subjectTypes}, {continuationToken} and {scopeDescriptor}

Answer (score 0):

Please check if my finding helps ,

*To get users using user descriptor we can use the below given API:-*

e.g:-

`GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users/{userDescriptor}?api-version=6.0-preview.1`

For more information please refer this ***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***|[**Get a user by its descriptor**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) & [***Use Postman with the Microsoft Graph API***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman)